# Does precompiling assets increase performance of your application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some gems for ruby on rails needs precompiling their assets. For example CKEditor for rails. I have integrated by [this guide](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor). There was some code for `assets.rb` that will add precompiling.

Then I have run `rake assets:precompile` and it created a lot of files, I mean **A LOT OF FILES**, inside my `public/ckeditor` path.

Does this precompiling make my application operate faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Here's a nice article about [how precompile works](http://www.sitepoint.com/asset-precompile-works-part/).

Essentially all of your CSS and JS is minified and put into a single file when possible.  This avoids the overhead of making multiple http requests to different resources.  Precompile also does some magic with cache control for those resources and images alike.

Comment: Joshua is absolutely right. As a small addition: [HTTP/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) will in the future greatly reduce the need for these kind of mechanisms.